# How to set equal spacing between letters so that word wrap works consistently

Tags: html, css, ag-grid

I have an angular component which generates a grid table (using ag-grid) with the header row being used as a calendar formatting the answer in FRI - 28.09 .
The problem being that because I have a word wrapped in place with

```
text-overflow: clip;
overflow: visible;
white-space: normal;
```

The grid is responsive and it's width changes which means that cells can sometimes can be wider. The date which includes 'FRI' (friday), break into word-wrapper later then all other dates because of 'I'. 
How can I make it consistent where it breaks without breaking the responsivnes of the cells and without chaning the font style to monospace.

Comment: Also a monospace css which is similar to open-sans would be an acceptable solution

Comment: Or setting break points for the ag-grid column width would be fine, but that's a whole different question

Comment: If you want to clip the string rather than let it wrap, use `overflow: hidden` and `white-space: nowrap`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow

Comment: I want it to wrap, but consistently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the best I could come up with... 
Since the cells are made with **ag-grid** the inside element for the text is something I could identify and set a fixed width on the class for the text. This way I can assure that the word wrap is always active without disrupting the responsiveness of the grid. 
This doesn't solve the issue of word wrap being consistent on amount of letters instead of amount of the space that letters take up.